# Identifying dangles and hanging roads in a map in geotools

Tags: geotools

Is it possible through geotools to identify and mark all the dangles and hanging roads(lines) in a .shp file representing a map. Any example would help me proceed forward.

So far I have found the below which gives me the number of dangles in the .shp files:

```
SimpleFeatureCollection col = featureSource.getFeatures();
SimpleFeatureIterator itr = col.features();
List list = new ArrayList();

while(itr.hasNext()){

SimpleFeature feature = itr.next();
Geometry geom = (Geometry) feature.getDefaultGeometry();
list.add(geom);
}

Polygonizer polygonizer = new Polygonizer();

polygonizer.add(list);

Collection dangles = polygonizer.getDangles();
Iterator it = dangles.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next());;
}
```

Please let me know if we can locate these on a map. Possibly, I require to highlight these marking dangled lines.

Answer (score 1):

JTS' `Pologonizer` returns a collection of the input `LineStrings` which are dangles. However, GeoTools prefers to display whole `Features` rather than raw geometries. So you either need to generate some new `Features` from the returned `LineStrings` or search through the input features to find matching Geometries.

So something like:

```
SimpleFeatureCollection col = featureSource.getFeatures();
List<Geometry> list = new ArrayList<>();
try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = col.features()) {

  while (itr.hasNext()) {

    SimpleFeature feature = itr.next();
    Geometry geom = (Geometry) feature.getDefaultGeometry();
    list.add(geom);
  }
}
Polygonizer polygonizer = new Polygonizer();

polygonizer.add(list);

Collection dangles = polygonizer.getDangles();
TreeSet<LineString> set = new TreeSet<>(dangles);
List<SimpleFeature> features = new ArrayList<>();
try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = col.features()) {
  while (itr.hasNext()) {

    SimpleFeature feature = itr.next();
    LineString geom = (LineString) feature.getDefaultGeometry();
    if (set.contains(geom)) {
      features.add(feature);
      set.remove(geom);
    }
  }
}
SimpleFeatureCollection newCollection = DataUtilities.collection(features);
```